# Splitting a string with uppercase

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Split a PascalCase string into separate words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216085/split-a-pascalcase-string-into-separate-words)
>   [is there a elegant way to parse a word and add spaces before capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103730/is-there-a-elegant-way-to-parse-a-word-and-add-spaces-before-capital-letters)

Is there a simple  way to split this string
"TopLeft" to "Top" and "Left"

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3216085/28736

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want it dynamic, meaning every time you find an upper case letter break it apart, I don't believe this is built in, but could be wrong; it's easy enough to write an extension method.

```
string output = "";

foreach (char letter in str)
{
   if (Char.IsUpper(letter) && output.Length > 0)
     output += " " + letter;
   else
     output += letter;
}
```

Comment: Good.  And I would embellish a bit by using a StringBuilder instead of a string for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string s = "TopLeft";
        List<int> splits = new List<int>();
        for(int i=0; i<s.Length;i++)
            if(char.IsUpper(s[i]))
                splits.Add(i);

        int splitstart = 0;
        foreach (int split in splits)
        {
            s.Substring(splitstart, split);
            splitstart = split;
        }
```