# Split string by uppercase words

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, c#-4.0

I have a string like the following:

```
HELLO: blah blah WORLD: woo woo FOO: foo foo
```

I need to split this string into 3 strings e.g.

```
HELLO: blah blah 
WORLD: woo woo 
FOO: foo foo
```

I tried to find pattern around the [:] but didn't help a lot.

Thank you.

P.S. C# or VB.NET code it's irrelevant to me. Both of these will work for me. Thx again

Comment: Regex would be universal (c# and vb)

Comment: While it is certainly not a simple task for a regex, before asking it is a good idea to check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079135/splitting-a-string-with-uppercase

Comment: Michal it's not even close to the solution. I checked all the answers here and none of them apply in my case. However thank you for your input.

Comment: @ElizabethDimova: Just stay calm, sometimes people overreact here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with :--

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split("HELLO: blah blah WORLD: woo woo FOO: foo foo", "(\s(?=[A-Z]))");
```

split the input string by space followed by capital latter.

Comment: Thank you, buddy. I didn't know that there are people who are here to help someone. Based on the downvotes and showing off a power i though that people come here to cure their frustrations. God bless you.