# Split a string at uppercase letters, but only if a lowercase letter follows in Python

Tags: python, split, text-mining, uppercase

I am using pdfminer.six in Python to extract long text data. Unfortunately, the Miner does not always work very well, especially with paragraphs and text wrapping. For example I got the following output:

```
"2018Annual ReportInvesting for Growth and Market LeadershipOur CEO will provide you with all further details below."

--> "2018 Annual Report Investing for Growth and Market Leadership Our CEO will provide you with all further details below."
```

Now I would like to insert a space whenever a lowercase letter is followed by a capital letter and then a smaller letter (and for numbers). So that in the end `"2018Annual"` becomes `"2018 Annual"` and `"ReportInvesting"` becomes `"Report Investing"`, but `"...CEO..."` remains `"...CEO..."`.

I only found solutions to [Split a string at uppercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216204/14635557 but could not rewrite it. Unfortunately I am totally new in the field of Python.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Even being new to Python coding, you should still try some coding and posting what you have tried before asking for solutions

Comment: understood, will try to make it better next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try using `re.sub` here for a regex approach:

```py
inp = "2018Annual ReportInvesting for Growth and Market LeadershipOur CEO will provide you with all further details below."
inp = re.sub(r'(?<![A-Z\W])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', inp)
print(inp)
```

This prints:

```
2018 Annual Report Investing for Growth and Market Leadership Our CEO will provide you with all further details below.
```

The regex used here says to insert a space at any point for which:

```
(?<![A-Z\W])  what precedes is a word character EXCEPT
              for capital letters
(?=[A-Z])     and what follows is a capital letter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting with regex:

```
import re
temp = re.sub(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)", r"\1", string).split()

string = ' '.join(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code below gives the required result.

```
temp = re.sub(r"([a-z])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", text)
temp = re.sub(r"(\d)([A-Za-z])", r"\1 \2", temp)
```

I still find complex regular expressions a bit challenging, hence the need to split the process into two expressions.
Perhaps someone better at regular expressions can improve on this to show how it can be achieved in a more elegant way.